# Microsoft Bot Framework SDK: Set up bot question

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service

I have a relatively simple question.
I am developing a chatbot using the Microsoft Bot Framework SDK in C #.
Among the various dialogues, I have one of "Registration" in which the bot asks the user for some information such as his name, age and interests.
In this case the questions are embedded in the bot's source code.

My question is the following:

**Is it possible to avoid embedding the bot's questions in the code?**

In this way, if in the future I need to modify the questions (for example remove the question about the age and insert one about the user's gender), I can do it without touching the source code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use QnA Maker [Service](https://www.qnamaker.ai/), an AI based cognitive service, to implement simple Question and Answer conversational patterns.
Here are the bot-builder [samples](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples#qna-maker-samples) using qnamaker.